# jquery fadein img background on mouse over, but not content indide

Tags: jquery, html, background, fadein, fadeout

Stuck a bit with jquery, kindly check `jsfiddle.net/7HXEF/1/`
DIV with background img, where background imd should be faded in and fadeout when mouse over. But div inside with link, should never fadein or/and out.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea, however if you have content inside a div which is transparent or semi-transparent, the content will mirror the opacity of it's parent.

I moved the content outside of the background, and contained them within a new container, and set it to trigger on mouse over content or background and now it seems to work how you want it to.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="box-side-link" style="background-image:url(http://st.datapic.ru/img/13-02/23/vlSI25yi3zLUuNCpKzBWNAK1G.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="mylink"><a href="#">001</a></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    // fade out on load
    $('.box-side-link').fadeTo(0,0.5);
});

$('.box-side-link, .mylink').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(ev) {
    ev=ev.type==='mouseenter' ? $('.box-side-link').stop().fadeTo(500,1) : $('.box-side-link').stop().fadeTo(500,0.5);
});
```

CSS:

```
.box-side-link, .parent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
}
.box-side-link {
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.mylink {
    position: absolute;
}
```

And here is a fiddle of it put together: http://jsfiddle.net/2ANut/1/

Comment: I'm just started with jquery :) Thank you! Works gr8, not if i dublicate DIV with same style, it fades out all DIVs http://jsfiddle.net/2ANut/4/

Comment: You will need to uniquely identify which div you want to fade. The jquery is based on fading the div with class `box-side-link`, both of your backgrounds have this class. You can keep this but use the closest `box-side-link` to the mousein by selecting the parent of the hovered item and finding the right `box-side-link` http://jsfiddle.net/2ANut/5/

Comment: I will as soon as i'll get 15 rep :)